# How to output to both mp4 and mpegts

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

Using h264 and aac, I've been trying to generate an mp4 and mpegts output in one command using the new [tee](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee) muxer.

Either it complains about a lack of the aac_adtstoasc bsf, or if global_header is set a lack of the h264_mp4toannexb bsf. However, I can find no way to add a bsf for one output and not the other: adding it as usual applies to both outputs, and the muxer options (between `[]`) do not accept bsfs.

Did the ffmpeg team a) document this feature poorly or b) render this combination of outputs impossible?

Comment: Before anyone asks, I'm pretty sure that if you can answer the question then my (gigantic) command line is not going to help.

Comment: Not only would the gigantic command line be useful; so would the gigantic console output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in ffmpeg 2.0 or below. Support for bitstream filters with tee was added in 2.1.

> ‘bsfs[/spec]’
>
> Specify a list of bitstream filters to apply to the specified output. It is possible to specify to which streams a given bitstream filter applies, by appending a stream specifier to the option separated by /. If the stream specifier is not specified, the bistream filters will be applied to all streams in the output.
>
> Several bitstream filters can be specified, separated by ","

[-- Documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#tee)

```
ffmpeg \
  -i in.mp4 \
  -c:v libx264 \
  -c:a libfaac \
  -flags +global_header \
  -bsf:v dump_extra \
  -map 0 \
  -f tee '[f=mp4:bsfs=aac_adtstoasc]out.mp4|[f=mpegts]out.ts'
```

Comment: N.B. for my setup, this was actually slower than three separate commands in sequence, so remember to test if you were assuming otherwise.